# Extract substring between first and second dot character instances

Tags: bash

How could I extract in bash only the part : `"cluster_000621"`
in:

```
RATTUS_littleBoy.cluster_000621.ok.ok.ok.ok
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can also utilize bash [substring removal](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to manipulate strings ([demo](https://ideone.com/G5TVoB))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use awk, sed or cut.

Using cut:

```
echo "RATTUS_littleBoy.cluster_000621.ok.ok.ok.ok" | cut -d. -f2
```

Separe using "." delimiter

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
echo "RATTUS_littleBoy.cluster_000621.ok.ok.ok.ok" | sed "s/^[^.]*\.\([^.]*\)\..*/\1/g"
```

detailed explanation:

```
s/          # substitute
^           # begin of line
[^.]*       # all char without '.'
\.          # only '.'
\([^.]*\)   # all char without '.' in argument1
\.          # only '.'
.*          # all chars
/\1         # replace with argument 1
/g          # global, on the line
```

Comment: tank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1):

bash's `read` builtin will parse it for you without spawning another process.

```
$: IFS="$IFS." read x val x <<< "RATTUS_littleBoy.cluster_000621.ok.ok.ok.ok"
$: echo $val
cluster_000621
```